# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.68.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: g++, gnu-make, dyld, otool, install-name-tool

I've got a compiled program `mybinary` that fails immediately with "image not found" when I try to run it. It isn't the *path* to the missing dynamic library that's the problem, it's that it needs to look at the library name that *doesn't include the version number*.

At execution of `mybinary`, I get this (edited for brevity):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.68.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

Running `otool -L mybinary` shows this (also edited for brevity):

```
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.68.dylib
```

I want it to look at `libicuuc.dylib` without the ".68". An `ls -1` shows it exists:

```
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.69.1.dylib
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.69.dylib
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.a
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.dylib
```

Because the version referenced in `mybinary` is 68 (lower than 69, thus preventing `Incompatible library version`), I can fix `mybinary` by executing the following:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.68.dylib /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.dylib mybinary
```

Now, `mybinary` launches just fine.

**The goal, though, is to modify the `Makefile` for `mybinary` so that it will link to `libicuuc.dylib`.
How can I do this?**

`mybinary` is deployed in a tar file to end users, and they are more likely to have a more current version of icu4c (in this example, 69) compared to `mybinary` in the tar file (in this example, 68).

1. Is there someway to tell the linker at compile time that I want to use `libicuuc.dylib` (no version# in the filename)? It would be fine if this behavior then applied to other linked libraries, i.e., I don't need to have it specific for `libicuuc.dylib`.
2. If that's not possible, I could live with modifying the `Makefile` to run `install_name_tool` but then my dilemma is that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get `libicuuc.68.dylib`. It's not part of the compile console output, and parsing the output of `otool -L mybinary` is going to be messy. Is there any easy and elegant way to get `libicuuc.68.dylib` for passing to `install_name_tool`?

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to do this.  The standard nomenclature for shared libraries is that the ABI is specified by the major number.  So, if you have a library foo.N and a library foo.M where N != M, that means there's some ABI difference making those two libraries incompatible and you can't assume that using the "wrong" one will work.  The version number is embedded _into the library_ and anything linking that library will include that version at link time.

Comment: If you really want to do it, you have two choices: either do as you're doing and change the version in the binary after it's been linked, or else use similar tools to change the version in the library before it's been linked.  I'm not a MacOS person and their tools are weirdly non-standard but you can search on how to change the link name of a shared library probably using similar tools as for modifying the binary.  I know of no "elegant" way to retrieve this data, other than scraping the output of tools like this.